# SerDe properties for Athena Table

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a Athena Table through S3 File.

S3 File is CSV file, with each of the column are of different datatypes.

Say int,string,Double,bigint,date.

Since its csv file, if i use the below properties, the string column separated by comma gets left shfited.

```
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://xxxxx-xxxx-xx/xxxx-xx'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'spark.sql.partitionProvider'='catalog')
```

Try modifying again as below, unable to query the table. It throws error converting decimal to string.  How do I create and query table for the CSV file with int,string,Double,bigint,date column datatypes

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 'QUOTE_CHARACTER'='\"', 'separatorChar'=',')
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "quoteChar" = "`", "escapeChar" = "\\" )
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
 's3://xxxxx-xxxx-xx/xxxx-xx'
TBLPROPERTIES ("skip.header.line.count"="1")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rU6B.png)

Comment: Can you post sample rows to your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: corporateID, corporateName, RegistrationDate, RegistrationNo, Revenue,
25467887,"Sun,TeK,Sol",20020529,7878787,12323.00000

above is how my csv file looks like
when i try to read via athena, here is how my result will be. not sure which serde properties  to use. csv file with string column
corporateID, corporateName, RegistrationDate, RegistrationNo, Revenue,
25467887        Sun                    TeK                       Sol                    20020529

Comment: corporateID, corporateName, RegistrationDate, RegistrationNo, Revenue,
25467887,"Sun,TeK,Sol",20020529,7878787,12323.00000

above is how my csv file looks like
when i try to read via athena, here is how my result will be. not sure which serde properties  to use. csv file with string
corporateID, corporateName, RegistrationDate, RegistrationNo, Revenue-----------------------------------
25467887        Sun                    TeK                       Sol                    20020529

Comment: Please edit your question rather than use comments